# Do directional derivatives require direction vectors to have unit length? If so, why?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have just started studying directional derivative from the book *Mathematical Analysis* by T.M. Apostol.

The directional derivative is the generalization of partial derivative. The partial derivative represents the rate of change of a function due to small change of one of the independent variables involved, whereas the directional derivative represents the rate of change of the function due to the small change of a point in it's domain along any arbitrary direction.

The concept of directional derivative is as follows :

Let $\mathbf{f} : S \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ be a vector valued function defined over $S \subset \mathbb R^{n}$. Suppose we are to find out the rate of change of $\mathbf{f}$ when we move from a point $\mathbf{c}$ of $S$ to a nearby point $\mathbf{c} + \mathbf{u}$ along a line segment. Since each point of the line can be taken as $\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}$ for some $h \in \mathbb R$, we can take $h$ sufficiently small so that $\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}$ is in $S$. Then the quantity

$$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac {\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c} + h\mathbf{u}) - \mathbf{f}(\mathbf{c})} {h}$$

if it exists is called the directional derivative of $\mathbf{f}$ at $\mathbf{c} \in S$ in the direction of $\mathbf{u}$.

I am having some difficulty here. According to my teacher's lecture notes, $||\mathbf{u}|| = 1$. For this reason the directional derivative of a given function $\mathbf{f}$ at a point along some certain direction may differ.

> Is there any significance of considering $||\mathbf{u}|| = 1$?
>
> If the answer to my question is affirmative, then why?

Comment: Some authors require normalization; others don't. The advantage to not normalizing is that it makes the directional derivative a linear operator. I have answered this question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/809376/why-normalize-and-the-definition-of-directional-derivative

Comment: Yes, there is a significance of considering $||u|| = 1.$ Because, $\frac{u}{||u||}$ is the unit vector, $\frac{hu}{||u||}$ represents the vector displacement while moving a distance of $h*||u|| = h$.

Comment: I find difficulty in understanding the concept in the link provided by you @symplectomorphic.In fact I fail to compare my defination of directional derivative to your's. Please be more explicit reminding the matter that I am a novice to this concept.

Answer (score 2):

The directional derivative $\mathrm D_u f(x)$ can be seen as the derivative of
$$ \gamma(t) = f(x + tu)
$$
at $0$. If we allow $\lVert u \rVert \neq 1$, we can define $\phi(t) = f(x + tu/\lVert u\rVert)$. Then
$$ \gamma'(t) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f(x + tu) = \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}f\left(x + (t\lVert u \rVert) \frac{u}{\| u\|} \right) = \|u\| \phi'(t)
$$
which results in **different directional derivatives along the same direction**. This might be undesirable.

Comment: Do you mean @Henry W. $f'(x + tu) = D_u f(x + tu)$?

Comment: Sorry,I also feel trouble to understand the fact that $\gamma' (t) = ||u|| \phi' (t)$.Please be more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very nice idea to view $D_u f(x)$ as a function of $u$, with $x$ fixed.  In convex analysis, it turns out that if $f$ is convex then the function $u \mapsto D_u f(x)$ is a convex function of $u$, and in fact is the support function of the set $\partial f(x)$ (under mild assumptions).  This is a beautiful connection between two different notions of "derivative" that are useful in convex analysis.  But we could not make this statement if $u$ were required to be a unit vector.

So I think the elegant / beautiful thing to do is to allow $u$ to be any vector, not necessarily a unit vector.